# Edit dynamic link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, dynamic, hyperlink

I am using a plugin to display a Facebook feed. Everything works great, except posts that contain mentions of other FB users don't link correctly. This is seems to be on Facebook's end as they do not add the parent url so the feed links -- parent URL + whatever the profile URL is.

I have tried using several jQuery methods to prepend the main Facebook URL, but I've had no luck with it as the plugin loads everything dynamically.

The method I tried using was

```
$( ".section-text a" ).attr( "href", function() {
   return "http://www.facebook.com" + this.href;
});
```

Here is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dima7b/r48L8/2/

If you hover over a mention in the demo I provided, for example "Andreas Varady" you will see it links to the jsfiddle parent URL versus the facebook URL.

I have asked help from the plugin author, but he does not know either. What would be the best way to prepend the main Facebook URL to links that are loaded dynamically.

Thank you

Comment: can you please give us the code that loads the feed dynamicly if its possible  ??

Comment: @Youness the code can be access here: [link](http://www.bernasovskiy.com/social-stream-test.js) and search for "function fbHrefLink" that should be it, but I'm not ultimately sure.

Comment: ok man sorry i wasn't here

Answer (score 0):

### **(UNTESTED & UPDATED)**

**try changing this (at the end of the file):**

```
jQuery('.dcsns-facebook .section-text a').each(function(i){
    var txt = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var href = decodeURIComponent(txt.replace("http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=", "")).split('&');
    jQuery(this).attr('href',href[0]);
});
```

**to this  :**

```
jQuery('.dcsns-facebook .section-text a').each(function(i){
    var txt = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var href = decodeURIComponent(txt);
    jQuery(this).attr('href',href);
});
```

Comment: That did not work, but I actually left out some of the code which is the code that matters. I updated the file I linked, and if you go to the very bottom you will see it, or look for `dcsns-facebook .section-text a` -- Would I follow the same pattern that you wrote?

Comment: i updtated my answer hope it helps

Comment: thanks, but it did not work. I am thinking this is really something to do with Facebook and maybe not the plugin itself unfortunately :/ Appreciate the help!

Comment: yeah , and sorry i couldnt help you :(